# Write a 2 digit int in c including only <unistd.h>

Tags: c

Assuming I don't have access to any C standard libraries I'm trying to print a 2 digit int using the write(x, x, x) function. 
I have only included `<unistd.h>` as per specifications. 
My current function gives me only the ASCII representation of the value I pass into it.

```
void my_print(int x)
{
  write(1, &x, 2);
}
```

Comment: Please post 1. What input you have passed ?  2. What output you are expecting ?

Comment: If you are not going to use any library function, you are going to have to write a formatter yourself, e.g. extract each digit from the integer using artithmetics and generate the appropiate character representation, etc.

Comment: Since `x` is of `int` type, last argument of `write` should be `4` byte on `32` bit machine. `write(1, &x, 4);`

Comment: the inputs can be any int from 0-99 for example x = 20 should return 20

Comment: @uneven_mark how would I go about doing this? I think that's what I'm looking for.

Comment: @Bizarre As I said, first start of by extracting e.g. the first digit of the number. You can do that with the help of the arithmetic operators. Then convert the `int` digit into the proper `char` representing that digit and `write` it. Do the same for the next digit, and so on...

Comment: @uneven_mark the reason I need a two digit int is because i will recursively be calling a function until the number reaches 99, so the two digits have to increment together.

Comment: @uneven_mark could you maybe help me maybe explain how to build a function print_int so to just print the two char's to screen and keep incrementing the two digit ints.

Comment: @Bizarre I first though this was an exercise, but now it seems you are using this as part of something else. Why are you doing this in the first place? What platform are you working on, that you have `unistd.h` but not the C standard libraries?

Comment: It's an exercise I've pretty much done the logic but having trouble just printing to screen.

Answer (score 1):

Use mod % and div to get upper and lower digit

```
int low = x%10;
int high = x/10; // could also have a sanity check for the range here
```

Then transform it to ascii by adding '0' 0x30 and write

```
putchar(high+'0'); // Let compiler transform to char 
putchar(low+0x30); // Or this if you trust magic constants more
```

From here it is easy to transform the code to use write function

```
#include <unistd.h>

void myprint(int x){
   char buf[]= {'0'+(x/10)%10, '0'+x%10};
   write(1,buf,2);
}
```

Comment: It'd be best to avoid magic constants. Why should anyone remember that zero is ASCII 0x30? Simply add `'0'` - it's a `char` literal, after all: `putchar(high + '0')` etc.

Comment: The question specifies that only `unistd.h` may be included, therefore `putchar` may not be available. You should use `write` instead.

Comment: thank you this should help, hadn't thought of doing the math operation and use modulo.

Comment: The advantage of remembering the magic constant is when you come to an extremely striped down environment or only have a hexdump for debugging. But yes you are right a '0' allows for the character set to be changed but then if it does is it safe numbers still come in order.

Comment: @Simson: The C standard requires the digits 0-9 be consecutive in the character set.